# Changing a face's direction towards light does not update its color

Tags: javascript, three.js

I construct a simple Geometry (a triangle) between 3 vertices, in a scene with directional light. (left triangle in the below image)

When I then change one of the vertices so that the triangle has a different angle towards the light, I want the color of of the triangle to reflect that (center triangle), but as you can see, the color remains exactly the same.

When I create a new triangle between the updated vertices (triangle on the right), the color is properly set (as expected).

[image: three js screenshot]

Question: how can I get the triangle to dynamically update its color when I change one of its vertices?

I've tried:

```
triangle.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
triangle.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
triangle.geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true;
triangle.material.needsUpdate = true;
```

Comment: Try `geometry.computeFaceNormals();` and `geometry.computeVertexNormals();`

Comment: this did the trick in combination with the accepted answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The impression that you're using or `MeshBasicMAterial` or `MeshLambertMaterial`. Try use `MeshPhongMaterial`.

http://jsfiddle.net/stdob/j8k7yhLp/4/show/lite